# php script to read from params.ini file

Tags: php, joomla

I run 2 applications on my site and want to use that same template for both. My Joomla site stores it's template config in a params.ini file in the following manner:

```
sidebara_width=150
sidebarb_width=300
mainbody_width=500
```

each parameter in 1 line no commas or semicolon after that. I want to use the same values for my other template. like `<div id="sidebars" style="<?php echo $sidebara_width ?>.px">`

I need a small php script which can read these values from the params.ini file and assign a value of `150` to a variable called `$sidebara_width,` assign a value of `300` to a variable called `$sidebarb_width` and so on.

Kindly help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is  a function called
[parse_ini_file](http://php.net/parse_ini_file)

you could use it like this

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file('path to file');
$sidebara_width = $ini_array['sidebara_width']
$sidebarb_width = $ini_array['sidebarb_width']
```

and so on

regards

Comment: Sweet thanks buddy. Will try this and get back to you with the result.

Comment: your welcome, make sure if it was correct to mark the answer as correct by clicking the checkbox next to the answer as seen on this picture http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-answers-accepted1.png  =D

Answer (score 1):

You might want to checkout the `parse_ini_file` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)

Otherwise you can use `preg_match_all` (https://www.php.net/preg_match_all) and use a simple RegEx to match it.

- Christian

Comment: So kind of you those links are really helpful. Thanks